# How to run method in User Control hosted in PopupWindowAction

Tags: c#, prism

I have a popup hosts my `User Control` (using Interactivity). When this popup closed using Window Close button, I want my `User Control` calls its method for cleaning up, how can I do that?

Comment: Do whatever cleanup is necessary in the callback that happens when the interaction is finished, see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35238759/prism-custom-confirmation-interaction/35239947#35239947 for a code example

Answer (score -1):

Inherit the `Interactivity` class, then override the `getwindows` method, pass your custom `INotification` that contains the window.

Comment: Could you include some code that demonstrates what you are trying to pose as an answer?