# Can I set text-wrapping mode for a long-text message to transfer the text to the next line in Prism 6.2. modal dialog?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, modal-dialog, prism

Sometimes the text of notification message for modal dialog is very long as you can see on the figure below.[image]This is not custom modal dialog but simple notification modal dialog which has a very long text mesage. This is the exception error-message produced by MODBUS protocol library that I use in my application. But SQL Server exceptions can also have such very long text messages about errors. By default, Prism 6.2 modal notification dialod displays a none-wrapped text. As a result of it, the modal dialog is very long and not all of the text of error-message is placed and displayed in the dialog. Below is the XAML markup for this modal dialog:

```
<prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding NotificationRequest, Mode=OneWay}">
    <prism:PopupWindowAction IsModal="True" CenterOverAssociatedObject="True"/>
</prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>
```

And below is View Model C#-code for this dialog:

```
public InteractionRequest<INotification> NotificationRequest { get; private set; }

public String NotificationStatus
{
    get { return this._notificationStatus; }
    set { SetProperty(ref this._notificationStatus, value); }
}
```

The folowing line of code is from View Modal constructor:

```
this.NotificationRequest = new InteractionRequest<INotification>();
```

And the following is method displaying modal notification dialog:

```
private void raiseNotification(string message, string caption)
{
    this.NotificationRequest.Raise(
           new Notification { Content = message, Title = caption },
           n => { this.NotificationStatus = "The user was notified."; });
}
```

Can I set text-wrapping mode for a long-text mesage (in XAML or in View Model) to transfer the text to the next lines in Prism 6.2. modal dialog?

Answer (score 0):

You can show any view that you want inside the `PopupWindowAction`, just add content to the `PopupWindowAction`:

```
<prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding NotificationRequest, Mode=OneWay}">
    <prism:PopupWindowAction IsModal="True" CenterOverAssociatedObject="True">

        <prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
            <views:MyFancyErrorPopup/>
        </prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>        

    </prism:PopupWindowAction>
</prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>
```

Now `MyFancyErrorPopup` can show your error message as a multi-line textbox or whatever you like...

EDIT:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ClientModule.Views.MyFancyErrorPopup"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
     xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
     prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
     mc:Ignorable="d" 
     d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Text={Binding Message}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        <Button Content="Ok" Command="{Binding OkCommand}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>


class MyFancyErrorPopupViewModel : BindableBase, IInteractionRequestAware
{
    public MyFancyErrorPopupViewModel()
    {
        OkCommand = new DelegateCommand( OnOk );
    }

    public DelegateCommand OkCommand
    {
        get;
    }

    public string Message
    {
        get { return (_notification?.Content as string) ?? "null"; }
    }

    #region IInteractionRequestAware
    public INotification Notification
    {
        get { return _notification; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty( ref _notification, value as Notification );
            OnPropertyChanged( () => Message );
        }
    }

    public Action FinishInteraction
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    #endregion

    #region private
    private Notification _notification;

    private void OnOk()
    {
        FinishInteraction();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Should I define a View I want to use inside PopupWindowAction as UserControl or Window?

Comment: Should I define a View Model for the View I want to use inside PopupWindowAction or not?

Comment: The content will be a `UserControl`, and wether or not you want to use a view model, is up to you, but I'd say use one. Look at this for a bit more complex example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35238759/prism-custom-confirmation-interaction/35239947#35239947

Comment: Your example is quite complex. Please give me a simple example just for my case.

Comment: How to pass an error mesage to this dialog and how to display it? Can I use here the call of raseNotification method as in case of displaying of simple notification dialog in Prism?

Comment: I changed '<interactionRequest:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>...' to <prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>... and all works nice. Thanks for your help.