# How to add 'Notification', 'Warning' and 'Error' icons on Prism 6.2 WPF modal dialog?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, modal-dialog, prism

In my Prism 6.2 WPF MVVM application I use notification and confirmation modal dialogs. Below is a definition of the View of a notification modal dialog used in my application:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CommonWpfControlLibrary.NotificationDialogPopupView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"             
         prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" MaxHeight="300" MaxWidth="600">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="20">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        <telerik:RadButton Content="OK" Command="{Binding OnOkPressedCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="50" Margin="0 10 0 0"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Below is the ViewModel of this dialog:

```
public class NotificationDialogPopupViewModel : BindableBase, IInteractionRequestAware
{
    #region IInteractionRequestAware Implementation

    public INotification Notification
    {
        get { return _notification; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _notification, value as Notification);
            OnPropertyChanged(() => Message);
        }
    }

    public Action FinishInteraction { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Fields

    private Notification _notification;

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public NotificationDialogPopupViewModel()
    {
        this.OnOkPressedCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnOk);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public string Message
    {
        get { return (_notification?.Content as string) ?? "null"; }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Commands

    public DelegateCommand OnOkPressedCommand { get; private set; }

    private void OnOk()
    {
        FinishInteraction();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And below is an example of how I use this dialog in my application. This is XAML from the View where I need to use the dialog:

```
<prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding NotificationRequest, Mode=OneWay}">
        <prism:PopupWindowAction IsModal="True" CenterOverAssociatedObject="True">
            <prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
                <commonControls:NotificationDialogPopupView/>
            </prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
            <prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="Window">
                    <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="NoResize"/>
                    <Setter Property="SizeToContent" Value="WidthAndHeight"/>
                </Style>
            </prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowStyle>
        </prism:PopupWindowAction>
</prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>
```

And this is the definition of method for visualizing of the dialog from the appropriate ViewModel where I need to use the dialog:

```
private void raiseNotification(string message, string caption)
{
    this.NotificationRequest.Raise(
       new Notification { Content = message, Title = caption },
          n => { this.NotificationStatus = "The user was notified."; });
}
```

And finally, the example of the dialog itself:
[image]
This is the dialog with error message. But as you can see there is no 'Error' icon in the left part of the client area of the dialog. So that I have a question: **How to add: 'Error' icon to a modal dialog containing an error mesage, 'Warning' icon to a modal dialog containing a warning message, and 'Notify' icon to a modal dialog containing a user-notifying message as it is implemented in WPF MessageBox modal dialogs?** Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The "pretty" way to make a modal dialog in WPF with Prism and MVVM Pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21301981/the-pretty-way-to-make-a-modal-dialog-in-wpf-with-prism-and-mvvm-pattern)

Comment: Is there any way we can add line breaks into content. Meaning showing message in two lines?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39202336/can-i-set-text-wrapping-mode-for-a-long-text-mesage-to-transfer-the-text-to-the/39204120#39204120), you're completely free as to design your `NotificationDialogPopupView`. It can contain, text, icons, whatever you put in there. The data comes from the `INotificationObject`, that is, your own implementation of it. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35238759/prism-custom-confirmation-interaction/35239947#35239947) for a simple example that transfers a number (could be an icon index or bitmap in your case) to the popup, and returns a number from it (you might want the index of the button that the user clicked).

Comment: If I want use one instance of NotificationDialogPopupView and dynamically put the appropriate icon on it. If it is an error message, I put 'Error' icon on dialog. But if it is only notification, I put 'Notification' icon on dialog. Is it possible?

Comment: The popup view is just another view, nothing special here besides it being shown through an interaction request instead of a regular navigation service call. For example, your view model can expose the resource name of the icon and the view fetches it from a resource dictionary. Or you create an enum and a converter from enum to icon/resource name. Or you add a `IsVisible` property to the view model for each of your icons.