# Show View that return a result (object) Prism

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, prism

I'm working on a MVVM app using Prism.

I need to show a view that return a value (selected object) from a DelegateCommand of another view.

Please, what you suggest ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PRISM that's an "interaction request".

There's an example in the samples you could download.
You can see the code on this page:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921081(v=pandp.40).aspx

See the item selection view.

If that doesn't suit for some reason then I have a different non-PRISM approach which you could probably adapt easier than the PRISM stuff.

Comment: Here's a somewhat real-life example of an interaction request https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35238759/prism-custom-confirmation-interaction/35239947#35239947 ... but the interaction request in it's current form might not stay around for too long, as the prism team doesn't really like it, see this discussion https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/864