# In MVVM, open context menu upon drag completion

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, drag-and-drop, prism

In a software that is highly interactive, the user can do drag and drop operations on a collection of `UserControl`s. Upon drop, they should be presented with a `ContextMenu` offering some choices on how to perform the action, e.g., copy the item, or swap positions if there is another item at the drop location.

Using the Prism framework, the ideal way of implementing this would be by means of the `InteractionRequestTrigger`, for instance:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding SomeCustomNotificationRequest, Mode=OneWay}" >
        <!-- some subclass of TriggerAction-->
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Copy" />
                <MenuItem Header="Swap" />
            </ContextMenu>
        <!-- end some subclass of TriggerAction-->
    </prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

This raises a doubt on whether to implement the `InteractionRequestTrigger` in the XAML of the `ItemsControl` containing the drag-and-droppable `UserControl`, or if it should go into the `UserControl` itself. In case of the latter, how would the various instances of that particular `UserControl` “know” which one is to react on the interaction request?

Second, the child element of an `InteractionRequestTrigger` must be a `System.Windows.Interactivity.TriggerAction`. It seems that this is not widely used for anything other than opening popup windows. The documentation on `TriggerAction` is quite sparse, and I don’t know how to go about implementing its `Invoke` method. Any pointer to documentation would be much appreciated!

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35238759/prism-custom-confirmation-interaction/35239947#35239947

Comment: @Haukinger It helps insofar as it highlights that I should probably subclass `ContextMenu` implementing `IInteractionRequestAware`. At least I think that this is the reason that a `SomeCustomNotificationRequest` raised in my drop handler class isn’t consumed. I saw that you’re the one who provided the accepted answer in the link you posted (which works flawlessly, by the way). Any suggestions?

Comment: Okay, it seems I’m getting somewhere: the Prism manual mentions that a custom notification request must be raised in the view model pertaining to the view that consumes it. Indeed, if I add an `EventHandler` with custom event args to my drop handler class (that the view model refers to anyway) and add a listener to this event handler in my view model, I can raise the custom notification request in that handler. The `InteractionRequestTrigger` now correctly invokes my `TriggerAction`. All that’s left are the visuals, I guess, and the `ContextMenu` callback, of course. Will post success here.

Comment: I'd design a pop window that looks like a context menu instead of actually deriving from that.

Comment: Well, it turns out that the `ContextMenu` itself was another tough cookie, but I solved the problem—and it’s not that hard, either, at least with 20/20 hindsight. I’ll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an `InteractionRequestTrigger` definitely *is* the way to go here, but since the `ContextMenu` control doesn’t reside in the same visual/logical tree as the control that defines it, one has to walk through some dark alleys.

Before coming to the actual code, I’d also highlight the reason I didn’t go for @Haukinger’s suggestion to use a popup window instead of a `ContextMenu`: while providing the advantage of making direct use of the properties I define for my custom `Notification` (plus the callback mechanism) by means of `IInteractionRequestAware`, I’d have had to implement some magic to make the popup window appear at the mouse cursor location. Plus, in my particular case, I’m manipulating the data model as a result of the context menu click, meaning that I’d have had to use dependency injection with the popup window in order to access the correct instance of my data model, which I frankly don’t know how to do, either.

Anyway, I got it to work smoothly with a `ContextMenu`. Here’s what I did. (I won’t post the obvious boilerplate code; just keep in mind that I’m using [Prism](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism) with the [GongSolutions Drag and Drop Library](https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop).

### A) Drop Handler

The drop handler class must be augmented with an event that we can call upon drop. This event will later be consumed by the view model belonging to the view that’s hosting the drag and drop action.

```
public class MyCustomDropHandler : IDropTarget {
  public event EventHandler<DragDropContextMenuEventArgs> DragDropContextMenuEvent;

  public void Drop(IDropInfo dropInfo) {
    // do more things if you like to

    DragDropContextMenuEvent?.Invoke(this, new DragDropContextMenuEventArgs() {
      // set all the properties you need to
    });
  }

  // don't forget about the other methods of IDropTarget
}
```

The `DragDropContextMenuEventArgs` is straightforward; refer to the Prism manual if you need assistance.

### B) Interaction Request

In my case, I’ve got a custom `UserControl` that’s hosting the elements I want to drag and drop. Its view model needs an `InteractionRequest` as well as an object that gathers the arguments to pass along with a click command on the `ContextMenu`. This is because the `ContextMenu` doesn’t implement `IInteractionRequestAware`, which means we’ll have to use the standard way of invoking command actions. I’ve simply used the `DragDropContextMenuEventArgs` defined above, since it’s an object that already hosts all the required properties.

#### B.1) View Model

This makes use of a custom notification request with a corresponding interface, the implementation of which is straightforward. I’ll skip the code here to keep this entry more manageable. There’s a lot on StackExchange on the topic; see, for instance, the link @Haukinger provided as a comment to my original question.

```
public InteractionRequest<IDragDropContextMenuNotification> DragDropContextMenuNotificationRequest { get; set; }

public DragDropContextMenuEventArgs DragDropActionElements { get; set; }

public MyContainerControlConstructor() {
  DragDropContextMenuNotificationRequest = new InteractionRequest<IDragDropContextMenuNotification>();
  MyCustomDropHandler.DragDropContextMenuEvent += OnDragDropContextMenuShown;
}

private void OnDragDropContextMenuShown(object sender, DragDropContextMenuEventArgs e) {
  DragDropActionElements = e;
  DragDropContextMenuNotificationRequest.Raise(new DragDropContextMenuNotification {
    // you can set your properties here, but it won’t matter much
    // since the ContextMenu can’t consume these
  });
}
```

#### B.2) XAML

As a sibling to the design elements of `MyContainerControl`, we define the `InteractionTrigger` for the notification request.

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
  <prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding DragDropContextMenuNotificationRequest, ElementName=MyContainerControlRoot, Mode=OneWay}">
    <local:ContextMenuAction ContextMenuDataContext="{Binding Data, Source={StaticResource Proxy}}">
      <local:ContextMenuAction.ContextMenuContent>
        <ContextMenu>
          <MenuItem Header="Move">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
              <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MoveCommand}"
                                           CommandParameter="{Binding DragDropActionElements}" />
              </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem Header="Copy">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
              <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CopyCommand}"
                                           CommandParameter="{Binding DragDropActionElements}" />
              </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
          </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
      </local:ContextMenuAction.ContextMenuContent>
    </local:ContextMenuAction>
  </prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

### C) Trigger Action and Other Magic

This is where things get tricky. First of all, we need to define a custom `TriggerAction` that invokes our `ContextMenu`.

#### C.1) Custom Trigger Action

The `ContextMenuContent` dependency property makes sure that we can define a `ContextMenu` as content of our custom `TriggerAction`. In the `Invoke` method, after a couple of safety checks, we can make the context menu pop up. (Mouse location and destroying the context menu after the user clicked an option is handled by WPF.)

```
public class ContextMenuAction : TriggerAction<FrameworkElement> {
  public static readonly DependencyProperty ContextMenuContentProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ContextMenuContent",
                                typeof(FrameworkElement),
                                typeof(ContextMenuAction));

  public FrameworkElement ContextMenuContent {
    get { return (FrameworkElement)GetValue(ContextMenuContentProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ContextMenuContentProperty, value); }
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty ContextMenuDataContextProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ContextMenuDataContext",
                                typeof(FrameworkElement),
                                typeof(ContextMenuAction));

  public FrameworkElement ContextMenuDataContext {
    get { return (FrameworkElement)GetValue(ContextMenuDataContextProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ContextMenuDataContextProperty, value); }
  }

  protected override void Invoke(object parameter) {
    if (!(parameter is InteractionRequestedEventArgs args)) {
      return;
    }

    if (!(ContextMenuContent is ContextMenu contextMenu)) {
      return;
    }

    contextMenu.DataContext = ContextMenuDataContext;
    contextMenu.IsOpen = true;
  }
}
```

#### C.2) Binding Proxy

You’ll note that there’s a second dependency property called `ContextMenuDataContext`. This is the solution to a problem that arises from the fact that a `ContextMenu` doesn’t live inside the same visual/logical tree as the rest of the view. Figuring out this solution took me almost as long as all the rest of this combined, and I wouldn’t have gotten there if it wasn’t for @Cameron-McFarland’s answer to [Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494226/cannot-find-source-for-binding-with-reference-relativesource-findancestor) as well as the [WPF Tutorial on Context Menus](http://wpftutorial.net/ContextMenu.html).

In fact, I’ll refer to those resources for the code. Suffice it to say that we need to use a binding proxy to set the `ContextMenu`’s `DataContext`. I resolved doing this programmatically via a dependency property in my custom `TriggerAction`, since the `DataContext` property of the `ContextMenu` needs the `PlacementTarget` mechanism to work properly, which isn’t possible in this case, since the `TriggerAction` (as element containing the `ContextMenu`) doesn’t have its own data context.

### D) Wrapping everything up

In retrospective, it wasn’t that hard to implement. With the above in place, it’s child’s play to hook up some commands defined in the view model of the view that hosts the `MyContainerControl` and pass those via the usual binding mechanism and dependency properties. This allows for manipulation of the data at its very root.

I’m happy about this solution; what I don’t like that much is that communication is doubled when the custom interaction request notification is raised. But this can’t be helped, since the information gathered in the drop handler must somehow reach the place where we react upon the different choices the user can make on the context menu.